# Join two tables based on multiple conditions and priority SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm trying to join two tables together that would return a classification of a region based on the city and postcode.

TABLE A contains information about the customer and their location

[image: Table A]

TABLE B contains information about suburbs, postcodes and regional classifications

[image: Table B]

I would like to match the two tables in order of preference:

1. Suburb and Postcode
2. Postcode
3. Suburb

I'm having a difficult time joining the two tables. I have this code and so far, it only matches the first preference. The classification returns a NULL if the postcode OR suburb is NULL.

```
SELECT 
A.*, B.Classification 
INTO NEWTABLE 
FROM TABLEA AS A 
   LEFT JOIN TABLEB AS B
      ON A.City = B.City
      AND A.Postcode = B.Postcode
```

I feel the solution is quite simple but I just can't get my head around the SQL language. I'm using Microsoft SQL. Thank you so much!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

This is a great place to use lateral joins -- `OUTER APPLY`, in this case:

```
SELECT A.*, B.Classification 
INTO NEWTABLE 
FROM TABLEA A OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) B.*
      FROM ((SELECT B.*
             FROM TABLEB B
             WHERE A.City = B.City 
            ) UNION ALL
            (SELECT B.*
             FROM TABLEB B
             WHERE A.Postcode = B.Postcode AND (A.City <> B.City OR B.City IS NULL)
            )
           ) B
      ORDER BY ((CASE WHEN B.PostCode = A.PostCode THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) +
                (CASE WHEN B.City = A.PostCode THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
               ) DESC
     );
```

This is structured so the query can take advantage of indexes on `B(Postcode)` and `B(City)`.

Assuming that the match by Postcode and City means that the *other* column is `NULL`, then you can also do this with `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
SELECT A.*,
       COALESCE(BCP.Classification, BP.Classification, BC.Classification) as Classification
INTO NEWTABLE 
FROM TABLEA AS A LEFT JOIN
     TABLEB  BCP
     ON BCP.City = A.City AND
        BCP.Postcode = A.Postcode LEFT JOIN
     TABLEB BP
     ON BP.Postcode = A.Postcode AND
        BP.City IS NULL AND
        BCP.City IS NULL LEFT JOIN  -- no match above
     TABLEB BC
     ON BC.City = A.City AND
        BC.PostCode IS NULL AND
        BP.PostCode IS NULL;
```

This is carefully structured to avoid duplicate rows.

Comment: Hi Gordon! Thank you so much!! The second code worked!

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to `LEFT JOIN` the same table 3 times and use a `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT A.*, COALESCE(B1.Classification,B2.Classification,B3.Classification) as Classification
INTO NEWTABLE 
FROM TABLEA AS A 
LEFT JOIN TABLEB AS B1
      ON A.City = B1.City
      AND A.Postcode = B1.Postcode
LEFT JOIN TABLEB AS B2
      ON A.Postcode = B2.Postcode
LEFT JOIN TABLEB AS B3
      ON A.City = B3.City
```

Comment: I think the `join` criteria onto the `B3` table needs changing?  Also, all your `join` conditions reference table alias `B` rather than their respective tables.